# #REF! cell error after deleting pivot table

Tags: excel, vba

How do I retain a formula in a cell after deleting a pivot table?

The scenario I am facing:

I have a worksheet with a pivot table ranging from A3 to B13. In cell D3 to D13 I would have static values in the cell. For each row from row 4 to 13 I would be adding values from B to D and would be storing the results in column E.

So for example, the E4 cell would contain the formula `=B4+D4`. If I were to delete the pivot table the formula in cell E4 would change to `=#REF!+D4`.

[image]

After I run a macro where I delete the pivot table, the formula in column E replaces values in column B with `#REF!`. The macro is simply this.

```
Sub DltPivotTablesFromWS()
    Dim pt As PivotTable

    For Each pt In ActiveWorkbook.ThisWorksheet.PivotTables
        TheWS.Range(pt.TableRange2.Address).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Next

End Sub
```

[image]

The problem occurs after deleting the pivot table. How do we avoid this problem where it changes the formula inside the cell?

Comment: Use sumifs() to calculate the sum, based on the criteria used to calculate the original values in B3 and D3. As you don’t show or explain that detail....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INDEX can reference a location of the worksheet that will not change when the referenced cell is deleted.

```
=index(B:B, 3)+D3
```

If you want to drag that formula down, get the *3* from a cell that won't be deleted.

```
=index(B:B, row(D3))+D3
```

Comment: Nice. This works. Is there a vba solution to this without having to change the formula in the cell?